# Time of Timepicker get's lost on screen rotate

Tags: java, android

I have an activity with following code.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // set time picker values
    TimePicker picker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.startTimePicker);

    picker.setIs24HourView(true);

    picker.setCurrentHour(10);
    picker.setCurrentMinute(15);        
}
```

So a time picker is set to a fixed time, this works as expected. 
But when I rotate the screen and the activity get's recreated the time picker show in all fields the same value - not the value set. This happens on one, two or more time pickers on screen.

Has anybody an explanation for this weird behaviour?

Comment: Where do you set startTime and endTime?

Comment: startTime and endTime are correctly set (checked with debugger). This is not the issue.

Comment: @Drejc When you rotate the screen, the activity's `onCreate` function is called again so the values are reset. This is normal. Do you mean something different?

Comment: Try it yourself ... the value is FIXED but it is not correctly set on rotate. I'm coming to the conclusion it is probably an Android bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue is resolved when you put the time picker *set* calls in *onResume()*.

This is really weird as onCreate gets also called on rotate and methods are hit,
but there must be some logic of the control itself called which causes that.

So here is the "fix":

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
     super.onResume();
     TimePicker picker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.startTimePicker);

     picker.setCurrentMinute(10);
     picker.setCurrentHour(12);
}
```